# Issues running flutter library for web

Tags: flutter, web, package

I have a package for flutter, something like live data for flutter.
The problem is that I can't run it on chrome,
I tried everything but just can't run it.
this is the code of the library:

https://github.com/itaishalom/flutter_live_data/tree/main

I'm getting :

Uncaught SyntaxError: Duplicate parameter name not allowed in this context
main.dart.lib.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stream_live_data')
at load__packages__flutter_live_data_example__main_dart (main.dart.lib.js:19:80)

Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out that I had function with capital name parameters.
Changing it to lower, fixed it.